# Execute Perl script from within Perl script with variables

Tags: perl

I believe I have this sort of correct.  I can print the variables no problem.  When passing the vriables to the ups check script nothing happeneds?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open FILE, "upslist.txt";

while ($line=<FILE>){
if ($line=~/^(.*?),(.*?)$/){
#print "ups:$1 string:$2\n";
do 'check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl -H $1 -C $2';
}        
}
```

upslist.txt

```
#ups
ups1.site,upsstring1
ups2.site,upsstring1
ups3.site,upsstring2
ups4.site,upsstring3
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: could you post some lines of `upslist.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using single-quotes here, which inhibits interpolation:

```
do 'check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl -H $1 -C $2';
```

Also, you probably wanted to use `system` here, not `do`.

```
system( "check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl", "-H", $1, "-C", $2 ) == 0 
   or die "system call to check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl failed: $?";
```

(Edited to use list form of `system`, and `or` instead of `||`.  My C++ was showing.)

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I get:
system call to check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl failed: -1 at ups_crunch line 11, <FILE> line 2.

Comment: You might need to put the full path to `check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl` there.  Also, if `check_snmp_mgeups-0.1pl` script isn't marked executable, then you might need to `chmod +x` it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a `local` copy of `@ARGV`:

```
while ($line=<FILE>){
    if ($line=~/^(.*?),(.*?)$/){
        #print "ups:$1 string:$2\n";

        local @ARGV = ("-H", $1, "-C", $2);
        do 'check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl';
    }
}
```

but if you are seriously trying to integrate some functionality from the `check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl` script into your main script, consider a redesign for `check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl` as a reusable module that you can import into your script, and access its functionality through a subroutine call rather than the clunky `do FILE` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mixed quotes here. You need to use ` instead of ':

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open FILE, "upslist.txt";

while ($line=<FILE>){
    if ($line=~/^(.*?),(.*?)$/){
        #print "ups:$1 string:$2\n";
        my $result = `check_snmp_mgeups-0.1.pl -H $1 -C $2`;
    }        
}
```